# GLM: Euler Angles to Quaternion

Tags: opengl, mathematics, opengl-es, rotation, glm

I hope you know **GL Mathematics** ([GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)) because I've got a problem, I can not break:

I have a set of **Euler Angles** and I need to perform **smooth interpolation** between them. The best way is converting them to **Quaternions** and applying **SLERP** alrogirthm.

The issue I have is how to **initialize** glm::quaternion with Euler Angles, please?

I read [GLM Documentation](http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.2/index.html) over and over, but I can not find appropriate `Quaternion constructor signature`, that would take three Euler Angles. The closest one I found is 
[angleAxis()](http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.0/a00184.html#a4412b01c376d9cfc9cc06b2d511d0f16) function, taking angle value and an axis for that angle. Note, please, what I am looking for si a way, how to parse `RotX, RotY, RotZ`.

---

For your information, this is the above metnioned [angleAxis()](http://glm.g-truc.net/api-0.9.1/a00279.html#ga4412b01c376d9cfc9cc06b2d511d0f16) **function signature**:

```
detail::tquat< valType > angleAxis (valType const &angle, valType const &x, valType const &y, valType const &z)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not familiar with GLM, but in the absence of a function to directly convert from Euler angles into quaternions, you can use the "rotation around an axis" functions (such as "angleAxis") to it yourself.

Here's how (pseudocode):

```
Quaternion QuatAroundX = Quaternion( Vector3(1.0,0.0,0.0), EulerAngle.x );
Quaternion QuatAroundY = Quaternion( Vector3(0.0,1.0,0.0), EulerAngle.y );
Quaternion QuatAroundZ = Quaternion( Vector3(0.0,0.0,1.0), EulerAngle.z );
Quaternion finalOrientation = QuatAroundX * QuatAroundY * QuatAroundZ;
```

(Or you may need to switch those quaternion multiplies around, depending on the order in which your euler angle rotations are intended to be applied)

Alternately, from looking through GLM's documentation, it appears that you may be able to convert euler angles -> matrix3 -> quaternion like this:

```
toQuat( orient3( EulerAngles ) )
```

Comment: good answer because it's less ambiguous about order of application.

Comment: @Trevor: +1, Hi Trevor, thanks for your good answer. This looks like the most practical solution here. I can easily switch between the rotation multiplication order. Possibly, the number of combinations is the reason, why Euler Angle to Quaterion conversion is not avaialble in GLM.

Comment: Although all the answers are good and valuable, in my opinion, _this_ is the most practical one. I would like to mark it as the _Accepted Answer_.

Comment: @Trevor: In Quaternion finalOrientation = QuatAroundX * QuatAroundY * QuatAroundZ;, **what kind of multiplication** have you meant? I am surprised, that GLM, does not overload `operator *` for Quaternion multiplication, so possibly, I will have to peform **multiplication manually**.

Comment: I mean, is the Quaternion Multiplication a **Dot or Cross** Product?

Comment: @Bunkai: you may want to study quaternions a bit more; quaternions have a well-defined multiplication (that is, an operator that takes two quaternions as input and returns another quaternion), and the concept of cross product doesn't really make sense for quaternions.  (And even dot products mostly make sense in a more limited fashion).

Comment: @Steven: hi, and thanks for your comment. Yes, you are correct, I need to understand quaternions more. I have read the book [3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development](http://www.amazon.com/Primer-Graphics-Development-Wordware-Library/dp/1556229119/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1307743377&sr=1-1) which is very good book indeed. I am in the beginning of implementing quaternions into practice, so I need to theoretical theoretical knowledge into practice. I know, I have a lot to lern, and my math book is open next to me.

Comment: @Steven: regarding quaternion multiplication, I understand it, that there are only two kinds of quaternion multiplications: **Dot** and **Cross** product. The more common is Cross prodcut, where the result is another Quaternion. As I later found out, GLM library calls the standard quaternion multiplication as the **Cross Product**. If you know about another multiplication Quaternion multiplication in GLM, that woud really hlep.

Comment: @Steven: regarding my knowledge about quaternions and another stuff. Yes, I am aware that I lack a lot of information now. As I mentioned, I have the math book next to me, and I have read key chapters serveral times. Now, I am in the most difficult beginnings, when, I need to put Quaternions into practice. I would like to kindly ask you and others to be patient, and to understand, that I am doing all I can, to get over this painful period as quickly as possible. I wish and need to learn this stuff very much.

Comment: @Bunkai the concept of quaternion multiplication is similar to matrix multiplication, it is neither dot nor cross product. If you want to understand the usage of quaternions, then get used to matrices and understand axis-angles, their basic concept is pretty similar to quaternions, the math is a bit more advanced, but once you understood axis-angles, then quaternions are not far away anymore.

Comment: @Maik: Hi Maik. Thanks for your adivce and support. Althouth I think, that I understand the above mentioned contcepts theoretically, when I come to praxis, I see, that I was missing few key details, and without them I am not getting desired results. Yes, you are right, I need to understand both concepts pracitcally, and then move forward. Thanks very much for your support. You helped me a lot to understand the topics.

Answer (score 21):

```
glm::quat myquaternion = glm::quat(glm::vec3(angle.x, angle.y, angle.z));
```

Where `angle` is a `glm::vec3` containing *pitch, yaw, roll* respectively.

PS. If in doubt, just go to the headers and look. The definition can be found in glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp:

```
explicit tquat(tvec3<T> const & eulerAngles) {
        tvec3<T> c = glm::cos(eulerAngle * value_type(0.5));
    tvec3<T> s = glm::sin(eulerAngle * value_type(0.5));

    this->w = c.x * c.y * c.z + s.x * s.y * s.z;
    this->x = s.x * c.y * c.z - c.x * s.y * s.z;
    this->y = c.x * s.y * c.z + s.x * c.y * s.z;
    this->z = c.x * c.y * s.z - s.x * s.y * c.z;    
}
```

Where `quat` is a float typedef for `tquat`.

Comment: That's quite ambiguous, what order would these apply in? Eulers are ordered rotations and the quaternion constructor here doesn't seem to care about that.

Comment: The function definition is the exact same as yours; I posted it in my answer if it mattered.

Comment: not the order of the arguments, the order of application of rotation. My answer contains the XYZ ordering, taken from the wikipedia article, however, we use ZYX ordering of application at my old company, and YZX at my current one. the x angle is still the first value in the vector / argument list in all cases, but the actual resultant transform is not the same.

Comment: I fixed my answer for the rotationQuat, so you can see how you could easily change the order. By default it accepts XYZ, but you can easily change that.

Comment: His answer didn't stipulate that the order mattered, he could figure out which is which by himself.
Its just a matter of moving around the x, y, z in the function call.

Comment: well, not really, as the value of the axis is independent of the order of application.

Comment: So how would you do a different order? (Genuinely interested)

Comment: if you start with the basic quaternions:
qx( cx, sx, 0, 0 )
qy( cy, 0, sy, 0 )
qz( cz, 0, 0, sz )
, then you build up the answer by deriving the final multiplications (I'm currently trying to do this so i can derive the final quaternion conversions for the ZYX one in particular)

Comment: It appears that the details are in the signs (the signs of the row sums for xyz

Comment: @Daniel: +1, Hi Daniel, and thatn you very much for your comment. In the first moment, I thougut, you were referring to built in GLM function called `rotationQuat()`. After I oublechecked, and noticed that the function is not in `glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp`, I understood that you provided your own function, and named it 'rotationQuat' :-) Regarding the order of Euler Angles, well, I think, I can modify the body of the function to suit my needs. It really did sound, like the function `rotationQuat()` is already withing the GLM. :-)

Comment: Hahaha no no! The rotationQuat is the name of the variable! Of the type glm::quat (a GLM quaternion). See line 58 of glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp.

Comment: @Daniel: you are perfectly right. I must have overlooked this Quaternion constructor.  Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: -1 for not mentioning the rotation order, which is very important for the question

Answer (score 9):

Solution is in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

using that:

```
sx = sin(x/2); sy = sin(y/2); sz = sin(z/2);
cx = cos(x/2); cy = cos(y/2); cz = cos(z/2);

q( cx*cy*cz + sx*sy*sz,
   sx*cy*cz - cx*sy*sz,
   cx*sy*cz + sx*cy*sz,
   cx*cy*sz - sx*sy*cz ) // for XYZ application order

q( cx*cy*cz - sx*sy*sz,
   sx*cy*cz + cx*sy*sz,
   cx*sy*cz - sx*cy*sz,
   cx*cy*sz + sx*sy*cz ) // for ZYX application order
```

Constructors for a quaternion, given an Euler (where application of rotation is XYZ or ZYX). However, it's only two of six possible combinations of Euler angles. You really need to find out what order the Euler angles are constructed when converting to transform matrix. Only then can the solution be defined.

In the old company I worked at, we had Z as forwards (like most graphics cards) so the application order was ZYX, and at my current company the Y axis is forwards and Z is up, so our application order is YZX. This order is the order you multiply your quaternions together in to generate your final transform, and the order matters for rotations are the multiplications are not commutative.

Comment: +1, hi and thanks for great answer. As I use **OpenGL**, the Z value goes out of the screen. In my application I perform **ZYX multiplication** order. Originally, I thought, that GLM has this functionality available, but I see, they have not implemented it yet, so one alternative is creating the conversion _manually_ , as you recommend.

Comment: This is the best answer here.

Answer (score 1):

```
vec3 myEuler (fAngle[0],fAngle[1],fAngle[2]);
glm::quat myQuat (myEuler);
```

fAngle must be in radians!

Comment: Was this a joke? Or did you you just not read the other answers (especially Daniel's)?